# Iniciar um serviço do Windows 10 por código Java

Tags: java

No Windows 7 eu usava o seguinte método para iniciar um serviço do Windows em Java:

```
static final String CMD_START = "cmd /c net start \"";

public static int startService(String serviceName) throws Exception {
  return execCmd(CMD_START + serviceName + "\"");
}
```

Porém, depois que atualizei para Windows 10 este método não funciona mais.
Poderiam me ajudar com um código que inicie um serviço do Windows e funcione no Windows 10?

Comment: creio que a melhor ferramenta para gerenciar servicos via linha de comando é o SC. Entretanto, não sei se a mesma está disponível no Windows 10 (creio que sim). Ver: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/133883/stop-and-start-a-service-via-batch-or-cmd-file

Comment: Eu tentei alguns desses comando e não funcionou no Windows 10... =/

Comment: qual é o erro que o Windows 10 apresenta?

Comment: Ao tentar iniciar o serviço do Tomcat por exemplo, aparece isso na console:

O servi�o de Apache Tomcat 7.0 Tomcat7 n�o foi iniciado.

Para obter mais ajuda, digite NET HELPMSG 3521.

Comment: E vc consegue iniciar normalmente pela janela de serviço do Windows 10, correto?

Comment: Consigo sim, normalmente!

Answer (score -1):

Para iniciar qualquer comando do SO, o código a ser utilizado é:

```
Runtime r = Runtime.getRuntime();
r.exec("CMD");
```

O comando deve está no PATH do sistema operacional.

Se a código acima junto com a configuração correta do PATH não permitir a execução, então existe alguma probabilidade de está relacionado a permissão, assim seria buscar em outros tópicos mostrando exatamente esse contexto: Administrador do SO não tem permissão para iniciar um serviço no windows 10.

Comment: Desculpa a pergunta colega, mas como que coloca o "comando no classpath"? Nunca vi essa expressão antes.

Comment: Errei o termo, é só PATH.

Comment: Imaginei que fosse, mas no PATH se colocam diretórios apenas, não?
Como que coloca um comando lá?

Comment: Vamos esquecer por hora o Java. Tente iniciar o seu serviço pelo terminal. Verifique se iniciou normalmente. Caso tenha não tenha iniciado, o problema não está no código e sim na configuração do SO.

Comment: Tentei iniciar direto pelo CMD, tentei iniciar o serviço do Tomcat por exemplo, digitando:

net start "Tomcat7"

E apareceu: Erro de Sistema 5. Acesso negado.

O que poderia ser?

Comment: Então o problema não é o código Java, o problema é na configuração do sistema.
O seu usuário faz parte dos administradores do SO?

Comment: Sim, meu usuário é administrador do SO.

Comment: Então seria bom fechar essa questão haja vista não ser problema no código o Java em si, e buscar em outros tópicos mostrando exatamente esse contexto: 
Administrador do SO não tem permissão para iniciar um serviço no windows 10.

Comment: Verdade colega. Mas eu consegui. Coloquei o eclipse como administrador e funcionou perfeitamente! Obrigado pela ajuda!

Comment: Então parabéns!

Comment: Creio que o @AndréHenriques pode mudar a sua resposta, incluindo a dica do Administrador. Assim a resposta pode ser aceita como a correta.